# Why is the border width not the same as what I set in html?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I set a border style of a div element in html as `border: 1px solid black;`. It shows correctly in most cases. But I just found a weird one, which is Chrome on Win 7 Home Premium, that the computed style shows the border width is 1.11111111px instead of 1px. Could someone tell me any possible reason that makes this happen?

Comment: Can you produce a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/e6qh6/ (I'm running Chrome on Win 7 Professional).

Comment: I'm running Chromium 22 on Ubuntu 12.10 and I can't reproduce your issue either. Do you have any other CSS set on your page?

Comment: Check your browsers ZOOM setting putting mine a 90% will show the computed border at 1.11111

Answer (score 3):

i am not sure and just have couple guesses:

1. Is that possible your style is overwritten by other style in the same css file?
2. Is your browser in 100% zoom? I don't think this will bother but I suggest you check it

Answer (score 1):

Quick question: Is there a specific reason your border has to be exactly 1px.

Also, as everyone else is saying, try to set your browser and your computer zoom at the default 100% zoom.

And the code: `border: 1px solid black;` is correct

Answer (score 1):

@chaonextdoor Did you use 'reset.css' in your project? Because most of the time if we do not specify any styles for any element, them browser uses its default settings on those places.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because of the zoom property of the browser. When zooming, be sure that it is always divisible by 100%.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [This answer has already been provided by another user over a decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831907/5351721). Please don't provide duplicate answers, especially to very old questions.